# Unknown column '...jdoDetachedState' in 'field list' gwt project

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, gwt

I have strange problems. When I ran my project without gwt, just hibernate - all is ok, but when I insert it code in gwt, this exception became appear.

```
PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Unknown column 'employee0_.jdoDetachedState' in 'field list'
```

I done this

```
List<Employee> list = session.createQuery("FROM Employee").list();
```

My query look like:

```
 Hibernate: 
    select
    employee0_.id as id1_1_,
    employee0_.born as born2_1_,
    employee0_.department as departme3_1_,
    employee0_.first_name as first_na4_1_,
    employee0_.jdoDetachedState as jdoDetac5_1_,
    employee0_.post as post8_1_,
    employee0_.salary as salary6_1_,
    employee0_.second_name as second_n7_1_ 
    from
    employee employee0_
```

and my class look

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    public String first_name;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    public String second_name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post")
    public Position post;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    public String born;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    public Integer salary;

    public String department;

    public Employee(){}

    ... public getters and setters
}
```

Other query works, but this don't. I've found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319853/unexpected-jdodetachedstate-column-when-using-hibernate-in-gwt-project  but can't inderstand how it can help.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and I've got solution at [this web-site](http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/jira/browse/NUCENHANCER-73) with adding these lines:

```
@Transient 
protected Object[] jdoDetachedState;
```

This helped for me. Maybe, this will help anybody.

Comment: Ok, but... your remark does not relate to the subject matter)
И не вижу проблем в написании текстов на других языках.

Comment: OK, if you don't see the problem, I'll direct you to the [**official**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) StackOverflow policy on using other languages. Talking about my remark, it's just educational matters. It's OK if someone shows me I'm confusing "it's" and "its" (though, I don't), the same situation with russian posts.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to you have not mentioned mapping of `jdoDetachedState` field in your `Employee` class
just add mapping of `jdoDetachedState` field in your `Employee` class

```
@Column(nullable=false)
public String jdoDetachedState;
```

also Make sure your ***table column name is same as Entity class field name*** otherwise use `name` attribute of `@Column` annotation  as

```
@Column(name = "column_name",nullable=false)
public String fieldName;
```

hope this will solve your problem

Comment: thank you, i will try it, but when i tried to put
 public Object[] jdoDetachedState; it didn't help

Comment: why you are taking Object[] ? what is the Data Type of jdoDetachedState column in your table ?

Comment: it is unexplainably, now i have Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate field name&signature in class file com/example/myproject/shared/model/Employee

Comment: maybe gwt and hibernate use different library for deserialization, because I deleted validation jars from gwt plugin for eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Now not understood problem. I had '**Department**' table. It worked, but when I added one column in table, it also begun failed with the same exception:

```
Unknown column 'department0_.jdoDetachedState' in 'field list'
```

Add

```
 @Column(nullable=false)public String jdoDetachedState;
```

didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution! when I added `jdoDetachedState VARCHAR(11)` column to my tables in mysql all begun works.

Answer (score 0):

For the simple  google app engine project(NON-maven)  you can solve this problem  by uncheck option the  **use datanucleus  JDO/JPA to access the datastore**

Step :

1. Go to the **Google app engine plugin option.**
2. click on **"Deploye to App Engine"**
3. click on **app engine project setting option**
4. Uncheck the option of **"Use DataNucleus JDO/JPA To access the datastore"**

   5. and deploy or Run

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution i dont know its  right way to program but it resolved my problem! I alter my table and added `jdoDetachedState` column of `text` column to my tables in mysql.
**Note : Don't add the jdoDetachedState in the  java file.**