# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'JDODETACHEDSTATE' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, google-app-engine, jdbc

I keep getting this error when using `Eclipse` persistence with `Google App Engine` in eclipse.

Below is the stack trace. Please let me know what could be causing this issue as the code was working before in `maven` without any issues.

```
 [EL Warning]: 2015-08-15 00:47:59.466--UnitOfWork(914108319)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
    Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'JDODETACHEDSTATE' in 'field list'
    Error Code: 1054
    Call: SELECT user_credential_id, JDODETACHEDSTATE, password, user_name, lecturer_id FROM user_credentials WHERE ((user_name = ?) AND (password = ?))
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
    Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=UserCredential sql="SELECT user_credential_id, JDODETACHEDSTATE, password, user_name, lecturer_id FROM user_credentials WHERE ((user_name = ?) AND (password = ?))")
    Aug 15, 2015 12:47:59 AM com.mana.school.attendance.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl doLogin
    SEVERE: Exception while validating login

Local Exception Stack: 

    Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
    Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'JDODETACHEDSTATE' in 'field list'
    Error Code: 1054
    Call: SELECT user_credential_id, JDODETACHEDSTATE, password, user_name, lecturer_id FROM user_credentials WHERE ((user_name = ?) AND (password = ?))
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
    Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=UserCredential sql="SELECT user_credential_id, JDODETACHEDSTATE, password, user_name, lecturer_id FROM user_credentials WHERE ((user_name = ?) AND (password = ?))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:646)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1805)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2706)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2659)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1197)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2879)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1607)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1589)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1554)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:382)
    at com.mana.school.attendance.dao.impl.UserCredentialDAOImpl.validateLogin(UserCredentialDAOImpl.java:60)
    at com.mana.school.attendance.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl.doLogin(LoginServiceImpl.java:49)
    at com.mana.school.attendance.web.LoginServlet.performLogin(LoginServlet.java:132)
    at com.mana.school.attendance.web.LoginServlet.service(LoginServlet.java:63)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:502)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: You could have put some effort into formatting it.

Comment: Posting it first time over here, not used to the tools for formatting.I have edited it now.

Comment: So removing the JDODETACHEDSTATE from the query statement should resolve the issue since the issue as caused by it, and you mentioned you don't want this column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown column '...jdoDetachedState' in 'field list' gwt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489658/unknown-column-jdodetachedstate-in-field-list-gwt-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not have a column called `JDODETACHEDSTATE` in the table `user_credentials`

Comment: I dont want this column, why is it there? The entity classes don't have them. Do I need to change some configuration or edit something. Please let me know if you know of any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Javy is right there is no such column in your table which you are referring

Take your select query for example

```
SELECT user_credential_id`, JDODETACHEDSTATE`, password, user_name, lecturer_id FROM user_credentials WHERE ((user_name = ?) AND (password = ?))
    bind =>
```

the JDODETACHEDSTATE is not present in your user_credentials table check with the table and if not necessary remove the field from the select query itself.